# Select the first N *groups* using mysql

Tags: mysql

To make it simple, let say I have a table with 2 fields - PERSON_NAME and COMPANY_ID with those pairs:

```
('a',1) ('b',1) ('c',2) ('d',2) ('e',3)
```

PERSON_NAME a and b are working in COMPANY_ID 1 and so on.

I would like to select all rows for the first 2 (or N) COMPANIES -

```
('a',1) ('b',1) ('c',2) ('d',2)
```

I don't know how many rows there are for each COMPANY_ID.

GROUP BY won't work here as I need all rows within each COMPANY_ID.

This one works -

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE COMPANY_ID in (SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY_ID
                     FROM T
                     ORDER BY 1 DESC
                     LIMIT N)
```

But since performance is an issue, it won't suffice (there are about 25k companies and about 5-15 persons in each company). N is usually 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this as a join instead:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM T join
     (SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY_ID
      FROM T
      ORDER BY 1 DESC
      LIMIT N
     ) TN
     on TN.COMPANY_ID = T.COMPANY_ID;
```

Explicit joins often perform better than `in` in the `where` clause.

Comment: In my case, it is only slightly faster. I would love to have "Limit distinct COMPANY_ID 300"...

Comment: @user1248826 . . . If you have an index on `T(COMPANY_ID)` then the query should run much faster.