# How to select the first N complete partitions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

*Note. I found a solution for this myself, but I would like to share my solution because the search results were really bad. This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18549925/8746648) and was answered there, I was not able to find it until writing this answer.*

Given the dataset below, how can I select the first N complete partitions?

```
 foo | bar
-----|-----
  1  |  a
  1  |  b
  2  |  c
  2  |  d
  2  |  e
  3  |  f
```

I do not know how to describe this better, but I want to partition the data by "foo" and only get the first N partitions. Maybe an example illustrates this better:

```
   N = 1

 foo | bar
-----|-----
  1  |  a
  1  |  b
```

```
   N = 2

 foo | bar
-----|-----
  1  |  a
  1  |  b
  2  |  c
  2  |  d
  2  |  e
```

```
   N = 3

 foo | bar
-----|-----
  1  |  a
  1  |  b
  2  |  c
  2  |  d
  2  |  e
  3  |  f
```

I use PostgreSQL but this is a more conceptual question and applies to any SQL implementation. All implementations have some sort of `SELECT TOP` or `LIMIT` functionality, however, it is usually very limited, some implementations even require it to be a constant value.

The following query works in PostgreSQL but it is not very nice:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM example
ORDER BY foo
LIMIT (
    SELECT SUM(count)
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM example
        GROUP BY foo
        ORDER BY foo
        LIMIT 2
    ) AS a
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at this the wrong way. The solution is to first select N distinct
values of "foo" and the join the table with itself.

```sql
SELECT b.foo, b.bar
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT foo FROM example ORDER BY foo LIMIT 2 ) AS a
JOIN example b ON a.foo = b.foo;
```

Essentially, the problem is solved by throwing all the values away except the one that is being partitioned by, then to apply the limit, and finally to add the required values again using a join.

[Try this out on db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fLPFbsNZGiPZz6hUkuyX6z/0)

Answer (score 1):

Using [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) + [windows function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) :

```sql
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        dense_rank() over (order by foo) as rank
    from
        example
)
select cte.foo,cte.bar
from   cte
where  cte.rank<=N
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fLPFbsNZGiPZz6hUkuyX6z/2